# How to graphical remote control an Ubuntu server?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vnc

I've tried googling and [store my research here](http://www.diigo.com/user/namgivu/graphical-remote-control).

I'm connecting my Windows 7 SP1 machine to an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu cloud server, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. What I have done is

1. Enabling Remote Desktop in Ubuntu ([link1](http://sidrit.wordpress.com/2008/08/03/enable-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu-from-command-line/), [link2](http://www.samlesher.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-704-enabledisable-remote-desktop-from-the-command-line))
2. Connect to my server using 1) [TightVNC](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.tightvnc.com/&rct=j&q=tightvnc&ei=PAYwTsi-L4e5hAftt4k9&usg=AFQjCNE9U3dmAZO4vHyHoBWlbsD9SbnXmw&sig2=Gurs0Is2r8-pbddyBRMsVg&cad=rja) and 2) [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/index.html) – I don't use [uVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/index.php) since it contains viruses.

But all of those result in `Connection failed`. I'm giving up!

*More Detail*
Ubuntu server to remote to: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (codename lucid)

My Windows: Windows 7 SP1

Answer (score 2):

Although I am not familiar with EC2, you have to check a few things.

First of all, make sure that your Ubuntu installation has a desktop manager installed (Gnome/KDE/iceBox...)

Then, make sure that Amazon allows for remote access using VNC and that they haven't blocked the necessary ports. You can probably find this information in EC2's FAQ.

A connection failed may be because the remote desktop connection in ubuntu isn't configured correctly, either because of networking and blocked ports, or simply because VNC is unable to connect to the desktop manager and thus has no virtual screen to send to your machine.

This is a brief guide to installing a GUI on an Ubuntu Server:

[Ubuntu Server GUI Install Guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html)

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu. Please show me how to check `desktop manager` installed or not.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to connect using SSH or whatever interface you are using now, logging in and then typing in 'startx' (no quotes). If this returns an error by the likes of "command not found" or similar, you don't have a graphical user interface installed and will have to start working on that. You might want to check with Amazon about user conditions first.

Comment: I've startx and get the error `Xauth: file /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority does not exist`. What should I do next Akseli?

Comment: I've tried `sudo startx` and get another error `Fatal server error: no screens found`. Do you have any idea Akseli

Comment: What you need to do is install Gnome and X11. I've added a guide to my answer above.

Comment: I've installed ubuntu-desktop by following your guide but still get `no screens` fatal server error. Do I need to restart my server after your guide's steps?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that you have to restart the server to get everything working correctly. Also remember to run the X11 configuration software, or modify the xorg.conf document according to instructions.

Comment: I've re-read the guide, and found that I didn't enable multiverse and univer as required `First you nee to make sure you have enabled Universe and Multiverse repositories`. I have uncomment lines in `/etc/apt/source.lists` which contain `multiverse` and `universe` - those include Ubuntu + `backprots` and `Canonical` repositories. Is that correct? I would be lovely if you brief the steps in your answer.

Comment: I got an issue: when executing the command `sudo aptitude install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl libmd5-perl`, I get the result `No candidate version found for libmd5-perl`; later on, it failed to install the downloaded `webmin` package due to the lacking of dependency on this `libmd5-per`. Please help!

Comment: I solve it myself on `libmd5-perl`. Please ignore my related comment above. Solution is at http://www.kelvinwong.ca/2010/05/22/installing-webmin-on-ubuntu-server-10-04-lts-lucid/

Comment: @askeli Though, after theinstall process I cannot open `webmin` homepage as https?//<my-ip>:10000/. Do you have any idea? Have you tried and ever succeeded?

Comment: @askeli And after all... again, I get the error `no screens found` when calling `sudo startx`. So sad and exhausted on my own. Hope you could give me some hints to continue.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Cygwin/X](http://cygwin.com/install.html) on my Windows 7 machine and I do X forwarding as follows.  First open a Cygwin terminal and enter this command:

`XWin :0 -clipboard -resize=randr`

Then open a new Cygwin terminal instance and do:

`DISPLAY=:0.0 ssh -c arcfour -fCY user@server gnome-session`

This is assuming you have already installed gnome on the server of course.